# Apache restart when developing python wsgi apps

Tags: python, windows, apache, wsgi

I am evaluating python for web development (mod_wsgi) and have noticed that on windows I have to restart Apache after changing my python source code. On Ubuntu the problem doesn't exists, probably because linux supports wsgi daemon mode.

Are there any way to have hot deployment during web development on windows, like configuring apache, replacing web server, some IDE, etc?

Comment: this probably because windows is piece of shit!, i dont use windows for developer in python or any language open source.

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4206000/1982962)

Comment: And more specifically http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/02/source-code-reloading-with-modwsgi-on.html

Answer (score 0):

Accordning to the links in the comments above, restarts after source changes are always necessary on windows. On linux you still need to touch the wsgi file after source changes. Is it only me that finds this being a major drawback, compared to PHP?