# Can't save datetime.now() to DateTimeField

Tags: python, django, datetime, python-3.x

I've defined a model as follows (Shortened it for the question)

```
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta

class Case(models.Model):
    received_email_sent = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)

    def send_received_email(self):
        message = settings.EMAIL_HEADER + self.case_received_email() + settings.EMAIL_FOOTER
        send_mail('Subject here', message, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, ['xxx@xxx.com'], fail_silently=False)
        self.received_email_sent = datetime.now()
```

and in the view I call send_received_email on an existing object. I know that the send_received_email block is being entered because I'm receiving the emails every time I test this out, but the `self.received_email_sent = datetime.now()` part is leaving that field as its default value (None) every time. Here's the relevant part of the view:

```
from logbook.models import Case

def job_email(request, case_id):
    case = get_object_or_404(Case,pk=case_id)
    case.send_received_email()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/jobs/'+str(case.case_id))
```

I have also tried an alternative method, where saving the field is done in the view instead of the model, like so:

models:

```
class Case(models.Model):
    received_email_sent = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    def send_received_email(self):
        message = settings.EMAIL_HEADER + self.case_received_email() + settings.EMAIL_FOOTER
        send_mail('Subject here', message, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, ['xxx@xxx.com'], fail_silently=False)
        #self.received_email_sent = datetime.now()
```

views:

```
from datetime import datetime
from logbook.models import Case

def job_email(request, case_id):
    case = get_object_or_404(Case,pk=case_id)
    case.send_received_email()
    case.received_email_sent = datetime.now()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/jobs/'+str(case.case_id))
```

I have also tried both of the above routes with various tweaks like removing the brackets on now() and changing `from datetime import datetime` to just `import datetime`. No joy. Thanks for having a look at this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `self.save()` at the end of `send_received_email()`.

Comment: Thanks. This is working for me now but only on Django's development server. When running with apache2, it sends the email and doesn't save the datetime.

Comment: Have you updated your prod server? Tried reloading or restarting apache?

Comment: I was using reload before but a restart did it. Why did this work? Does apache not run the python code as is?

Comment: Maybe this link could help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206000/django-apache-mod-wsgi-having-to-restart-apache-after-changes