# Django on Apache2 - Restart Server when making changes?

Tags: python, django, apache2, mod-wsgi, restart

right now I'm trying - for the first time - to deploy a Django-Application on a Apache2 with mod_wsgi and it's still not working the way I wish it would. Anyway, I'm arguing with my Admin who says I don't have to restart the server after making changes to my python code, only if there are changes to the .conf-files.
The tutorials online are also not that useful for this specific problem! Some say "A", some say "B" and some don't mention this topic at all.

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName webapp.company.local
        ServerAlias cmp-workbench.company.local
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/cmp-workbench
    #for django
        Alias /static /var/www/cmp-workbench/static
        <Directory /var/www/cmp-workbench/static>
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/cmp-workbench/cmp_workbench>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                Require all granted
            </Files>
        </Directory>
        WSGIDaemonProcess cmp-workbench python-path=/var/www/cmp-workbench python-home=/var/www
        /cmp-workbench/cmp_workbench
        WSGIProcessGroup cmp-workbench
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/cmp-workbench/cmp_workbench/wsgi.py

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_cmp-workbench.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_cmp-workbench.log combined
    </VirtualHost>
```

```py
    import os
    import time
    import traceback
    import signal
    import sys

    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
  
    sys.path.append('/var/www/cmp-workbench-stage/cmp_workbench_stage')
    sys.path.append('/var/www/cmp-workbench- 
    stage/cmp_workbench_stage/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages')

    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 
    'cmp_workbench_stage.settings')

    try:
        application = get_wsgi_application()
    except Exception:
        # Error loading applications
        if 'mod_wsgi' in sys.modules:
           traceback.print_exc()
            os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT)
            time.sleep(2.5)
```

Can someone who already deployed this way answer to my problem?
Thanks and a great weekend!

Comment: what kind of errors you've got (apache log) ? share with us your conf and wsgi.py files

Comment: Here's an update with my code. I actually don't get an error, The site just keeps loading!

Comment: Thanks for the link, but it still doesn't answer the question wether to restart the server everytime after making changes to my python code.

Answer (score 1):

in the most cases, you won't need to restart `apache` each time you make changes to python files. your sysadmin was definitely right. `apache` as web server is meant to serve and handle http requests (among other things) and not dealing with the execution of scripts (python, php ..)

as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4206134/12368419), and after you make some changes in your python files, simply running `touch wsgi.py` command will do the trick to force the daemon to reload since the timestamps of the file (`wsgi.py`) is updated.

refer to https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/touch.1.html

> Update the access and modification times of each FILE to the current time.